# Program Efficiency & Readability

Tags: c++, performance, memory

I want to know which program will be more efficient (memory usage) and why? The first program has lesser variables but more computations. Can you really say? All the program does is find the largest of 3 numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    if((num1 > num2) && (num1 > num3)) {
        return num1;
    } else if((num2 > num1) && (num2 > num3)) {
        return num2;
    } else {
        return num3;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num1, num2, num3;
    cout << "Enter first number" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter second number" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "Enter third number" << endl;
    cin >> num3;
    cout << "Maximum value: "  << max(num1, num2, num3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

OR

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int maximum(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int largest;
    if (num1 > num2) {
        largest = num1;
    } else {
        largest = num2;
    } if (num3 > largest) {
        largest = num3;
    } return largest;
}

int main() {
    int number1, number2, number3, max;
    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin >> number2;
    cout << "Enter the third number: ";
    cin >> number3;
    max = maximum(number1, number2, number3);
    cout << "The maximum value is " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I want to know if it is bad to give the same variable names in the main() and the max() functions? (In program 1)

Comment: tag: [tag:~~purformance~~]

Comment: It is useless to ask. You could benchmark, but most compilers could optimize both with similar speed.

Comment: In your example I say there is absolutely no need to optimize. You are not running max() a million times in a loop you are running it 1 time. The difference if there is one will likely be a few nanoseconds.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just starting out. While I have only this program to show you, what I mean is how I can reduce memory usage or cpu usage? Lesser variables means lesser memory usage and more computations mean more cpu usage right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the assembly of an optimizing compiler to reach a conclusion

See e.g. **[this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e5bb56f5c53c322)** on **[godbolt.com](http://goo.gl/aGqCQB)** ¹

[image]

The **[other](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a83e49822d9bfad2)** on **[godbolt too](http://goo.gl/7TtwB8)**: ¹

[image]

#### Looks like `maximum` is more efficient using these optimization flags on GCC

---

¹ appears the godbolt permalinks might not be working. It's easy to paste the snippets yourself. I use `rand()` and `return` to avoid the compiler optimizing it all out

Comment: You should provide also some results.

Comment: can you even english?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean?

Comment: I've added the goods. I wanted to make it pretty and meaningful. Sorry to keep you waiting

Comment: @Babbzzz _"I did not understand what you mean?"_ Yeah of course.

Comment: @Bot No of course not! It's the disassembly. If you **click on the link** then you'll see the C++ source side by side.

Comment: @sehe Thanks. I think I get it now. Looking into the Assembly equivalent of the program, we can know the exact number of cycles that the program would require? I'm new to all this. Sorry about that. Hope to get better soon.

Comment: Are you promoting this godbolt site? I didn't see any disassembly listings when I followed the link, and I didn't see any buttons or instructions either.

Comment: @sehe thanks for the link. that's a cool find. bookmarked.

Comment: @Babbzzz I've added the full comparison now. Looks like `maximum` ends up generating more optimized code (assuming that the one `double` was a typo)

Comment: @JonathanWood I had also included the source in Coliru links though, and I've even included images of the relevant disassembly listings. I'm not promoting coliru ***or*** godbolt. They're just awesome tools to use. If the links don't work, complain at godbolt.org :) Or just copy/paste the snippets in there for full effect. Cheers

Comment: @sehe thank you again because on further inspection I totally understand what you mean. Thanks for the tools.

Comment: @Babbzzz Cheers. Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are different flavors of *efficiency*. One program can make more efficient use of memory, while another executes faster. So the first step is to be more precise on the type of efficiency you are after.

That said, a few bytes here and there are just not even worth considering on virtually all computer platforms. So simplifying the code to run faster, even if a little more memory is used, is generally a good approach.

There is no problem with using the same variable names in different functions, unless they cause confusions.

Comment: Okay. So if I need the program to run faster I'll use the second program and lesser memory would be the first?

Comment: Yes, but the amount of memory saved in the first is almost not worth considering. It would be more of an issue if megabytes or even gigabytes of memory were involved.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'm liking programming. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to go down the avenue of writing readable code in the first instance.

If performance is an issue the do some analysis. Always remember the 80/20  rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle

So to answer your question I do not know as it depends on the OS/compiler options.

Comment: Do you mean I should work on making the code more readable?

Comment: One is assuming the `double` bit is an oversight. But I would go for the 2nd option as I think that is more readable. As for readability I think there is not a lot wrong with either. Just tidy up formatting and comments. Also be a bit more consistent with the braces

Comment: I have adjusted the formatting of both the programs, how are they now?

Comment: @Babbzzz - I have just chucked them through my IDE to tidy it up. But that is not the only way. There are others and some strict rules. ESA has a good set - see ftp://ftp.estec.esa.nl/pub/wm/anonymous/wme/bssc/bssc2000%281%29i10.PDF

Comment: Thanks for the document. I just skimmed a bit and made some changes. Thanks for all the help. Happy New Year.

Comment: And to you - the advice in that document is very good

Answer (score 0):

I would personally write it like this:

```
int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}

int main()
{
    int number1, number2, number3;
    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin >> number2;
    cout << "Enter the third number: ";
    cin >> number3;
    cout << "The maximum value is " << max(number1, max(number2, number3)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: WoW! That's great logic. I like this one. Cool. I've got a lot to learn. Do you have any beginner tips for me? :)

Comment: ***Do you have any beginner tips for me?*** Make your code readable. Optimize only when necessary.

Comment: Thank you. Is my code readable now? Or any suggestions to improve that?

Comment: @Nathan Nice logic but computational steps are more. See the link in the post sehe gave and copy and paste your code there.

Comment: When I use my max and use `return max(rand(), max(rand(), rand()));` in `main()` it actually produces less assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd algorithm, except for the "double", is bound to be faster because is uses less conditional branches - always 2, while the 1st algorithm needs at least 2 conditional branches, and sometimes more.

You might consider to omit an assignment:

```
int max(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    if(num1<num2) num1=num2;
    if(num1<num3) num1=num3;
    return num1;
}
```